# I am writing postgresql data to file using bash and psql. I need the column headers written to the output file

Tags: bash, postgresql, psql

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash/
PGPASSWORD='*******' psql -h host_name server_name user_name -t -A -F "," -c "select b.id AS booking_id, b.hotel_id as hotel_id, b.invoice_no as invoice_no, b.guest_id as guest_id from bookings b" > /home/ubuntu/scripts/food_suggest/automate/pgsql_data.csv;
```

Current output:

```
12345, 1111, ABCD1234, A111 
12346, 1112, ABCD1235, A112 ...
```

Required output:

```
booking_id, hotel_id, invoice_no, guest_id
12345, 1111, ABCD1234, A111
12346, 1112, ABCD1235, A112
...
```

Comment: Why don't you use `copy to stdout` or `\copy`? With that you can control the CSV output format much better.

Comment: What is the function of option `-t`?

Comment: @Cyrus - Thanks for pointing this. I went back and read psql [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/app-psql.html]. Works fine now.

Comment: @Cyrus - Can you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I do it from bash + psql with simple COPY command - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html
Use params `CSV HEADER` and maybe `FORCE QUOTE` if you have commas or " characters in strings. Otherwise it works OK.

For json export I use `COPY (select row_to_json(...` without `CSV` param. Both works well. I use it for export from PG to Bigquery.